# Ошибка добавления данных в таблицу

Tags: c#, wpf

Пример кода:

```
DBModel curDB = new DBModel();

            string RequestsDBPath = saveDir + @"RequestsDB.xml";
            if (!File.Exists(RequestsDBPath))
            {
                PersonClass person1 = new PersonClass("Серверный", "Краб", "Утилитович", "OUP_2");
                PersonClass person2 = new PersonClass("Пользовательский", "Тюлень", "Флудилович", "IT_D112");

                DataRow row = curDB.Requests.NewRow();

                row["Id"] = 1;
                row["SM Id"] = "SR366312";
                row["Desctription"] = "TestDesc";
                row["Initiator"] = null;
                row["Worker"] = null;
                row["Status"] = "InProgress";
                row["Creation Date"] = DateTime.Now;
                row["Changing Date"] = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);

                curDB.Requests.Rows.Add(row);

                curDB.Persons.Rows.Add(person1);
                curDB.Persons.Rows.Add(person2);

                curDB.WriteXml(RequestsDBPath, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
```

[image]

на curDB.Persons.Rows.Add(person1); получаю исключение о недопустимости null значения в параметре FIO(Ключ таблицы);

```
public class PersonClass
{
    public string SecondName;
    public string Name;
    public string ThirdName;
    public string FIO;
    public string Location;

    public PersonClass()
    {

    }

    public PersonClass(string SecondName, string Name, string ThirdName, string Location)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.SecondName = SecondName;
        this.ThirdName = ThirdName;
        FIO = string.Format(@"{0} {1} {2}", SecondName, !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) ? Name.Substring(0, 1) : null, !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ThirdName) ? ThirdName.Substring(0, 1) : null).Trim();
        this.Location = Location;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Upd:
 Написал конвертер PersonClass => DataRow

```
    public System.Data.DataRow toDataRow()
    {
        var row = MainWindow.curDB.Persons.NewRow();
        row["Name"] = Name;
        row["SecondName"] = SecondName;
        row["ThirdName"] = ThirdName;
        row["FullName"] = FullName;
        row["Location"] = Location;
        return row;
    }


curDB.Persons.Rows.Add(person1.toDataRow());
```

Answer (score 1):

Старайтесь не передавать неявные параметры в класс, это нагружает интерпертатор.

На вашем месте объявление

```
 PersonClass person1 = new PersonClass("Серверный", "Краб", "Утилитович", "OUP_2");
```

я бы заменил на

```
PersonClass person1 = new PersonClass(){
Name = "Имя",
SecondName = "Фамилия",
ThirdName = "Patronymic",
Location = "Расположени"}
```

А в PersonClass ФИО обьявил следующим образом

```
  public class PersonalClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    public string ThirdName { get; set; }

    public string FIO => $@"{SecondName} {(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) ? Name.Substring(0, 1) : null)} {
            (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ThirdName) ? ThirdName.Substring(0, 1) : null)}".Trim();
}
```

Учтите, при таком подходе, параметр FIO получает только условный Get аттрибут, вы не можете записать в него собственную переменную в любом месте кода.

P.S. Код отработал в запись в БД для сущности базы данных 
PersonalClass без поля FIO, с полем FIO нужно изменять CRUD действие.

Comment: Не совсем понял о чем идет речь. CRUD?

Comment: «это нагружает интерпертатор» — какой интерпретатор, простите?

Comment: Судя по всему DataTable не умеет работать с кастомными классами. Нужно передавать объект как Datarow.